# Show loading activity Webkit

Tags: ios, swift

I want to show activity when pages are loading.

It's probably simple but I'm a beginner..
Tried a couple of things but can't really tell you what I've tried, I don't understand it...

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {



    @IBOutlet weak var myWebView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       let url = URL(string: "https://www.zzzway.com/takephotoapp.php")
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)

        myWebView.load(request)
    }

}
```

I want to get a loading animation or any visual to show the user it's loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `UIActivityIndicatorView` as below,

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    private var activityIndicatorView: UIActivityIndicatorView = {
        let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
        activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        activityIndicator.color = UIColor.darkGray
        return activityIndicator
    }()

    @IBOutlet weak var myWebView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.myWebView.navigationDelegate = self

        self.activityIndicatorView.center = self.myWebView.center
        self.view.addSubview(self.activityIndicatorView)

        let url = URL(string: "https://www.zzzway.com/takephotoapp.php")
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)

        myWebView.load(request)
    }

}

extension SecondViewController: WKNavigationDelegate {

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didCommit navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        self.activityIndicatorView.startAnimating()
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        self.activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()
    }
}
```